# How can I export the QTP script under "Test Script" tab in QC?

Tags: qtp

How can I export the QTP script under "Test Script" tab in QC?

Comment: Why don't you elaborate more on what you want to accomplish, and why? Surely we can help you better then.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all -- it is a viewer only.

You can go to the expert tab, mark some code, copy it, and paste it into a text editor. That code won't be too usefull, though, because it probably references repository items or other stuff that is part of the test, or its settings, like environment variables, parameters, and so on.

So I think you cannot really export from the QC "test script" tab.

You'd need to install a suiteable QTP version, connect to the QC project, and open the test in QTP. Once you have it open there, you can use the "Export to ZIP file" feature, or simply "Save as..." to save the complete test into a separate location outside of QC.